# Related to spectrum

Tags: operator-theory

Let $T$ be a bounded self-adjoint operator on $\mathcal{H}$, let $\mathcal{K}$ be a closed invariant subspace under $T$. Can we say $\sigma(T|\mathcal{K})\subset \sigma(T)$? Where $\sigma$ stands for spectrum?

Comment: Do you mean $T(K) \subset K$ or $T^{-1}(K)=K$?

Comment: $T(\mathcal{K})\subset \mathcal{K}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that regardless of any spectrum assumption, $T$ maps vectors orthogonal to $\mathcal{K}$ (let us denote $K’$ this state) to elements of $K’$. 
Let $P$ be the orthogonal projection to $\mathcal{K}$. This implies that $T-\lambda I$ commutes with $P$ for any scalar $\lambda$. Then, should $T-\lambda I$ be invertible, its inverse would also commute with $P$, and thus map $\mathcal{K}$ into itself. Thus we would have $(T-\lambda I)_{|\mathcal{K}}$ invertible.

Comment: This answer (while being correct) needs a little bit more details as it does not mention self-adjointness. The assertion is surprisingly wrong for normal operators, though.

Comment: Can you provide a counterexample @Klaus?

Comment: @mathlover  Take the forward shift on $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ and $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ as the closed invariant subspace.

Comment: Klaus: the self-adjointness is used to show that if $x$ is orthogonal to $\mathcal{K}$, then so is $T(x)$.